# How can I fix a secure boot failing to grub when I installed 0.3.1?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, uefi, live-cd, grub

Boot into the system in UEFI mode failed.. Why does 0.3 support UEFI but 0.3.1 doesn't?

**Bug Reports:**
[0.3.1 UEFI / Secure Boot support incompatible](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1493099)
[Freya UEFI install boots to grub prompt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

[I can't boot into my system after a fresh install for 0.3.1 in UEFI mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492256)

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thumbs down doesn't solve any problem, the bug won't go away.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can't boot Elementary OS in UEFI mode after clean install.

Comment: StackExchange is not the place for bug repots.

Comment: I dunno. Haven't activated Uefi on my system. Running here Linux Mint and elementary OS in Bios mode. If you don't use Windows I would suggest you to change your system to Bios

Comment: Nice translation! 8m47x!

Comment: @8m47x Please post your answer here, and try to make your question titles questions guys!

Comment: Why does somebody change it to the wrong topic?

Comment: I have also installed while online, but end up with the same issue.

Comment: For reference, http://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair may present a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 has been released and fixes many of these issues. If you are installing or working on 0.3.1 and are experiencing these issues, we recommend you upgrade.

---

### Keep in mind that this is only a workaround!

> **[Rob Hartley (8ob):](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801/comments/5)** This is only a workaround though. The real question is why this happens in the first place. I did not receive any errors during
>   installation that would suggest grub failed to configure the system properly.

---

- Install Elementary 0.3.1 as normal (no special partitioning).
  Follow: [elementary.io - Installation](https://elementary.io/de/docs/installation#download-elementary-os)
- Boot will end in `grub shell`. Enter:
  `configfile (hd` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Select one and add `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
  Example: `configfile (hd0, gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- Open terminal after boot and type:
  `cd /boot/efi/EFI/grub`
  `sudo cp grubx64.efi grubx64.efi.backup` (just in case)
  `sudo rm grubx64.efi`
  `sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi`

**Source:** [Freya UEFI install boots to grub prompt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

Comment: "As normal" ? As stated elsewhere, it is not currently possible to ship both legacy and EFI grub at once. As such, you _must_ connect to the internet to install on an EFI computer. Practically all other distributions are going down the other route of making EFI always work and legacy be broken on older machines. Perhaps it's worth noting there are no reports of this happening if installing while connected.

Comment: We all connected to the internet while installing the system, and it failed to boot into the system. Why does Ubuntu, Mint, Manjaro, OpenSUSE, and elementary OS Freya 0.3 have no issue with booting in UEFI mode, but 0.3.1 does?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you can either have the Grub EFI or Grub Legacy installable offline, but not both. All those other systems favour the older standard, but elementary was trying to provide more recent support. Apparently it hasn't helped much, and the decision is being reconsidered.

Comment: When instructed to "Enter: 
configfile (hd and press TAB. Select one…" which one am I supposed to select? The GRUB partition or the partition where ElementaryOS was supposedly installed?

I've tried all three available ( (hd0,gpt1) which is a FAT partition about 500MB,  (hd0,gpt2) which is "ext*"about 250MB and  (hd0,gpt3) which says no known filesystem detected, about 250GB) and sadly no success.

Since you say to open terminal after boot, I assume that the next step is to reboot. Should this be with GRUB's reboot command or the hardware power switch? Also, you mean boot to the USB?

Comment: It works but need a small adjustment! At first entering `configfile (hd0...` will not work. Simply add the path like this `configfile /efi/grub/....`

Comment: I have also seen some strange booting issues with a multi-boot/multi disk configuration ... if the first disk is GUID and the second is not ... on some ubuntu derivatives (also elementary) i was having issues getting grub to install after i deleted one on my distros ... a real PITA ... i needed to install fedora and that let me get grub up and working again