# Can't boot into elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I have never installed Linux on a machine before and I am having issues.

I'm using an HP Omen laptop and wanted to install elementary OS on it in way so that I could use Windows 8.1 (already installed) or elementary OS. I followed the installation guide on [elementary's website](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#download-elementary-os) and was able to boot from the flash drive. I selected the option to install elementary OS, followed the onscreen prompts, selected to install elementary OS alongside Windows, and chose my partition size. The installation went successfully and informed me that to use the installation, I had to restart my machine.

Upon clicking restart, the machine booted straight into Windows. I restarted the machine, went into the BIOS, and looked at the boot order options. A new option had appeared called something along the lines of `GRUB`. I selected to boot to this and restarted the computer.

This time, instead of booting straight to windows, the computer booted to a black screen with some text on it.

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported...
```

From here I understand that I can enter some commands, however, I have never used Linux before and I am unable to get elementary OS to boot. I have searched for and looked through some guides, but I don't understand them well enough to solve my issue.

I would like to know how to get elementary OS to start up, or if I did something wrong during the installation and what I can do to fix it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try the answer of this
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failure-when-i-installed-0-3-1