# Black screen after install

Tags: system-installation, boot

I'm on Sony Vaio laptop; I booted from USB and tried elementary which worked well. I then installed using the entire drive with the "Download updates while installing". The install finishes and I click the "Restart" button. Then I get a black screen.

It's actually a terminal, but I can see one letter at a time in top left of the screen. I tried *reboot* which worked.

I tried installing without internet and had the same results. I haven't been able to install it. It's odd that I could use elementary OS when booted from USB, but it wouldn't work via install.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried replacing `quiet` and `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` which ended up with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I fix a secure boot failure when I installed 0.3.1?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failure-when-i-installed-0-3-1)

I should temporary solve your problem, Freya 0.3.1 doesn't work correctly in UEFI mode.

### Keep in mind that this is only a workaround!

> **[Rob Hartley (8ob):](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801/comments/5)** This is only a workaround though. The real question is why this happens in the first place. I did not receive any errors during
>   installation that would suggest grub failed to configure the system properly.

---

- Install Elementary 0.3.1 as normal (no special partitioning).
  Follow: [elementary.io - Installation](https://elementary.io/de/docs/installation#download-elementary-os)
- Boot will end in `grub shell`. Enter:
  `configfile (hd` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Select one and add `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
  Example: `configfile (hd0, gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- Open terminal after boot and type:
  `cd /boot/efi/EFI/grub`
  `sudo cp grubx64.efi grubx64.efi.backup` (just in case)
  `sudo rm grubx64.efi`
  `sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi`

**Source:** [Freya UEFI install boots to grub prompt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

Comment: I can only see one letter of the terminal, so if I type "reboot" I can only see "r", then "e", then "b" and so forth. Only the letter I type is visible. I wouldn't be able to complete all those commands.

Comment: What! I have never had that problem before, sorry.