# Grub failure, Intel Core i7 6700 Skylake

Tags: boot, grub

I have a grub failure after I install the elementary 0.3.1 freya. There is NOWwindows or other Linux OS installed , solo elementary. I got a Intel Core i7 6700 Skylake CPU, Asrock z170 motherboard.

I later tried the Ubuntu 15.04, no problem booting, but have serious bug: whenever I watch Youtube, it dies, mouse frozen, no response at all.

Anyone has idea how to deal with it ? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I use the method posted here [How can I fix a secure boot failing to grub when I installed 0.3.1?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failure-when-i-installed-0-3-1), and I did boot in !!!!!

For the second problem, I enable the i915.preliminary_hw_support=1. Still testing, but for now, everything is OK.

The kernel is 3.19.0-28

update: still have the problem similar to ubuntu 15.04, watch youtube, then die

update: try the 4.3 RC1 kernel, solve the problem!