# Not able to install elementary 64 bit OE 0.3.1 freya on HP 8740w

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, 64-bit

Before it worked in the beginning of Ubuntu 14.04 installation (same with Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.2) after hitting F6 and checking either one of:

`acpi=off`, `nolapic`
or `nomodeset`.

Must be something with the HP BIOS since on my newer desktop PC (also with nVidia card) installation went smooth. There is not much to change there, though, just checking/unchecking UEFI.

Any clues, please?

Thank you,
Marek

Comment: I meant, e OS, of course. Boot either from USB or DVD, same thing.

Comment: No, it's not about old BIOS. It's about the e OS installation package. I've tried now Ubuntu 15.04 installation on that HP, after checking nomodeset Ubuntu installation went ahead. Too bad, e OS is so simple and beautiful, er well...

Answer (score 0):

### Keep in mind that this is only a workaround!

> **[Rob Hartley (8ob):](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801/comments/5)** This is only a workaround though. The real question is why this happens in the first place. I did not receive any errors during
>   installation that would suggest grub failed to configure the system properly.

---

- Install Elementary 0.3.1 as normal (no special partitioning).
  Follow: elementary.io - Installation
- Boot will end in `grub shell`. Enter:
  `configfile (hd` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Select one and add `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
  Example: `configfile (hd0, gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- Open terminal after boot and type:
  `cd /boot/efi/EFI/grub`
  `sudo cp grubx64.efi grubx64.efi.backup` (just in case)
  `sudo rm grubx64.efi`
  `sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi`

**Source:** [Freya UEFI install boots to grub prompt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

Comment: " configfile (hd0, gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg" - error file name

Comment: Are you serious? That was my answer to this: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1884/1193 !! ??

Comment: @8m47x Answers posted on stackechange are licensed in such a way as they can be reproduced. In this instance, I'm not sure this is the answer to the question, but if it is it's the question that will be closed, not this answer.

Comment: @8m47x should I have just linked your answer? I saw it on a couple other threads and didn't think too much of it.

Comment: @Marek you have to choose the root partition you installed eOS to as you are aiming to point the grub to the correct config.

Comment: I'm not sure :/

Answer (score -1):

Rob,

I'm getting error after error, that's why I'll stick to Mint 17.2 on that HP notebook and I still have elementary OS on my prime computer.

Thanks anyway.

BTW
Cinnamon Mint installation has one additional option:
- Install in Compatibility Mode.
This works.