# can't boot to os Freya 0.3.1

Tags: release-freya, grub

[image]

I test install freya on dell vostro 5480 UEFI (installed 1 os)
I'm not good at English!

Answer (score 1):

[Freya has a known UEFI bug. You can find details here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

[Here is a sister thread that walks through the fix.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)

Please let me know if you need anything explained and I will try my best to expound on their solution.