# After installation, when rebooting i get the grub instead of elementary os

Tags: release-freya

After i install elementary os, when i restart the computer i get the GNU GRUB screen instead of the operating system. I have an intel i5 processor and nvidia gt740 graphics card.

Comment: i just grabbed the newest iso, and receive the same problem

Answer (score 0):

[Freya has a known UEFI bug. You can find details here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

[Here is a sister thread that walks through the fix.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)

Please let me know if you need anything explained and I will try my best to expound on their solution.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this all i did was boot into the live cd connect to wifi or ethernet
then run these commands into the terminal:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

once boot repair opens click advanced options then go to grub options then check purge grub before reinstalling then click apply 
once it is done shutdown the laptop take out the live cd then it should boot as normal

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to fix it, is to install ubuntu alongside with elementary OS. Ubuntu make right grub with two OS. After that you can delete Ubuntu ..

Comment: I think it is unrewarding to install another OS to fix a boot problem.