# Boot to GRUB after fresh install

Tags: system-installation, boot, grub

So I've read up on the forum that this is a recurring problem, but this might give just a little more insight.

I installed elementary OS (latest version) on my laptop. The SSD was clean and formatted. 
When the installation was done, I rebooted and came onto the grub error.

I tried this solution, but it did not work for me.
[Comment 5 for bug 1492801](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801/comments/5)

When i did do this, I got an error when i tabbed to look for a configfile. it stated:

- hd0 hd1 hd2error: failure reading sector 0xe8adb0 from hd0
  and then some more read errors from hd0 and hd2
  (hd 1 is swap)

I'm looking for a fix and will update if i do find one.

Answer (score 0):

[Freya has a known UEFI bug. You can find details here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

[Here is a sister thread that walks through the fix.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)

Please let me know if you need anything explained and I will try my best to expound on their solution.

Comment: Well, whenever i do the fix, i get read errors (as you can read in my question).
So I am completly stuck at the grub.

Comment: How old is the drive? Have you tried any disk scanners to see if the bad sectors are actually there? Also, I apologize for not recognizing that detail when i initially read your question. Any luck with other debian-based distros like Ubuntu or Mint?

Comment: Ubuntu is what i'm currently running. after multiple failures with multiple images of elementaryOS, i installed ubuntu to make sure it worked, and it hasn't failed yet. Also, Disk scanners tell me there is no problem with my SSD

Comment: Is the SSD partitioned with a GPT table? What partition scheme did you use?