# during the boot black screen and the words grub

Tags: grub

After the system is installed in the BIOS at all lost all the disks. And sometimes they are, but during the boot black screen and the words grub. How to fix it? Can'T install. New laptop i7, 12 RAM

Comment: I think that you are having this problem. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1?rq=1

Comment: Tell me please, is enter me in your black box or boot with a live cd? And enter in the terminal   >>>Boot will end in grub shell. Enter:
configfile (hd and press TAB. Select one and add /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Example: configfile (hd0, gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Open terminal after boot and type:
cd /boot/efi/EFI/grub
sudo cp grubx64.efi grubx64.efi.backup (just in case)
sudo rm grubx64.efi
sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi

Comment: I will not accept commands https://pp.vk.me/c622318/v622318680/4711f/05Vikc8s_6M.jpg  https://pp.vk.me/c622318/v622318680/47126/AtLNRG6bG7M.jpg   https://pp.vk.me/c622318/v622318680/4712d/GcuqkytPiIk.jpg