# Broken bios-Grub idk

Tags: system-installation

Well, finally I come here. after a lot of problems, I installed elementary OS Freya with my live USB erasing **ALL** my macbook pro disk but it was not a solution. Now, I turn on my mac and nothing happens... still in white and after a question mark and thats all. I enter using the live USB with the Try elementary OS option and I see the partitions with Freya but I don't know why WHY! it doesn't start with elementary OS T_T.

Pd. I would answer all your question, send information and follow your indications because I thing that there is the best place so solve my problem. Thanks!

*Update* I've uploaded a video in order to illustrate the problem. [Video](http://youtu.be/rxJ-FZFyfuo)

Answer (score 1):

[Freya has a known UEFI bug. You can find details here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801)

[Here is a sister thread that walks through the fix.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)

Please let me know if you need anything explained and I will try my best to expound on their solution.

Comment: Hi, they say that "Install Elementary 0.3.1 as normal (no special partitioning).
Follow: elementary.io - Installation

Boot will end in grub shell. Enter:"  But I don't get the grub shell. Just white. and when I try to select a partition to run with alt, nothing appears. Thank you very much

Comment: I uploaded a video showing you how is the starting process.

Comment: is your boot partition mounted as the EFI sys partition or /boot? Are you sure you have a GUID partition table (GPT) on your drive?

Comment: I really don't know, how can I know it?

Comment: [Open a terminal window in a live environment and follow these steps](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/parted-command-examples/)

Comment: Perfect, there is the print command http://pastebin.com/PbM0QECG

Comment: "If your Macbook spends 30 seconds with "white screen" before GRUB shows, try booting from your Mac OS X install disc, select language, then click Utilities->Terminal, and enter:

bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot --legacy

Assuming that the bootloader is on sda1, otherwise /dev/disk0s2 if it's on sda2, etc."

Try this. [Source 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) [Source 2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook)