# UEFI bug fix not working HP Stream 13

Tags: uefi

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I've been through the forums, and tried the suggested solutions but I still can't get elementary to boot. (Not sure of the version but downloaded it last night.) Clearly it seems to be the same issue (though I'm sure I had a web connection.) The test boot from the USB stick worked fine. I did a clean install (no windows backup) and now am stuck at GNU GRUB v2.02~beta2-9 screen.

I tried hitting 'c' and enter as suggested in one fix post, but get 'error: can't find command 'c'.' So, moving on, I have tried all combos of configfile HD 0 through 4, and gpt 0 through 4, and even substituted msdos for gpt (as I found in a post) with no success. I'm mostly flying blind taking shots in the dark. I get what is happening and can follow directions but am otherwise a noob with GRUB, Linux etc. so I can't diagnose why the fix isn't working.

Forgive the abbreviated descriptions above as I am typing this on my phone. When typing the GRUB commands I am following the posts to the letter.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through this issue myself.  It looks like you already saw [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1/1884#1884), so I would recommend the following instead:

[Bootloader Issue with Freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/bootloader-issue-with-freya)

Comment: Thank you! The comment that suggested this command: configfile /efi/grub/grub.cfg is what did the trick. (I had to type the entire command as the tab froze the line and didn't complete the suggestion. )

Comment: So, now I am trying to repair the issue as I am booting from the USB drive.  Per part two of the fix, I get to this step and get this response: /boot/efi/EFI/grub$ sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi’
any ideas @RootFAIL or others? Thanks!

Comment: @oneofbillions - So that's a copy command. You need to put the entry that you want copied AND the new  file destination/name. This is one line " sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi". "Sudo cp A B" means that you are copying file A, and saving the copy in a new destination with the name B. The slashed part is the destination, and the part at the end is the file name.

Comment: @oneofbillions - Maybe try copying and pasting the code into a wider text box (for instance text edit, notepad...) so you can see where the line breaks are.

Comment: @oneofbillions - just a warning that elementary is a fairly new OS based on Ubuntu, so it would be extremely useful to understand terminal commands, as you may need to use it at some point. I recommend reading through and testing commands on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal   I hope it helps!  (It's also the most elegantly designed OS I have seen, and once you get over the steep learning curve for terminal, it's immensely powerful and can be quite fun).

Comment: hey @RootFAIL, just wanted to say THANKS! from my internal boot install of Freya.  I'd still have a blue brick if not for your help! (Now when it boots though, it runs through a series of installs and asks me for a password prompt before it will install... is that a consequence of the workaround? Perhaps this will all be fixed in an update?)

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  Maybe post a new question?  With details and pictures if you can.