# Bootloader Issue with Freya

Tags: boot, grub, uefi

Update:  I found a solution!

[I am having the same problem as this person, but the solution is not working for me.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1/1884#1884)

I am booted into a grub prompt with minimal bash editing. My partitions are:

- boot loader in /dev/sda
- /boot in sda7 (Primary Ext2)
- Swap in sda8 (Logical)
- / in sda9 (Logical Ext4)
- /home in sda10 (Logical Ext4)
- The rest are windows partitions (dual boot)

So I tried the following:

```
configfile (hd0, gpt9)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Which only gets me:

```
error: filename expected
```

I tried all the other partitions (1 through 10) just to be sure, but they all get the same error.

---

**Miscellaneous**

When I enter

```
configfile (hd
```

I get

```
hd0 hd1error: failure reading sector 0xfc from 'hd1'.
error: failure reading sector 0xe0 from 'hd1'.
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd1'.
```

When I enter:

```
configfile (hd0,gpt
```

I get {I leave out the partition sizes after gpt2, but they are there.  I can retrieve them if necessary}:

```
Possible partitions are:
Partition hd0,gpt1:  Filesystem type fat - Label 'SYSTEM', UUID 14E4-FCC4 - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 102400KiB
Partition hd0,gpt2:  No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 103424KiB - Total size 921600KiB
Partition hd0,gpt3:  No known filesystem detected 
Partition hd0,gpt4:  No known filesystem detected 
Partition hd0,gpt5:  No known filesystem detected 
Partition hd0,gpt6:  No known filesystem detected 
Partition hd0,gpt7:  Filesystem type ext* - Last modification time 2015-10-09 20:11:06 Friday, UUID d9e87737-12df-4b32-98fb-c928101860a0
Partition hd0,gpt8:  No known filesystem detected 
Partition hd0,gpt9:  Filesystem type ext* - Last modification time 2015-10-09 20:05:04 Friday, UUID 6322aa7b-461e-493a-9d50-d03e83e1e543
Partition hd0,gpt10:  Filesystem type ext* - Last modification time 2015-10-09 20:05:09 Friday, UUID 4415c308-5b3f-47eb-b1f1-f69d8c39e00b
```

Comment: Hey can you try that with an extra space in it? `configfile (hd0, gpt9) /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Also, take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair and let me know.

Comment: @LewisGoddard It doesn't work with an extra space, and I answered my own question after a few hours of struggling with it.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution hidden in the comments.  Run this on your grub screen:

```
configfile /efi/grub/
```

and hit tab (you may need to wait half a minute for it to load)
It should give you a list of possible files. I chose cfg

```
configfile /efi/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as solving your question.

Comment: @bigbang - I can only do that in 8 hours.  They impose time rules on accepting your own answer.