# Tried to Dualboot W10/Elementary. Greeted by a Grub command screen. What do I do?

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I installed Elementary on my laptop. When I boot the computer, I just get a GRUB screen. What am I supposed to do? This isn't part of the tutorial I was following...

Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoEtS.jpg

BIOS shows the Windows Boot Manager and the GRUB screen. Installed Elementary with UEFI.
Very confused..

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to say this is probably a duplicate, but you should be able to find the [answer here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1884/2654).
If that doesn't work, [go here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2422/2654).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Boot using your live CD. Then you need to run these 3 commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Boot repair will now open. Click on "advanced options" and search for the option that mentions "purge grub". Than click "recommended repair" and follow the on screen messages. When that's done you can reboot and if everything went right it will work now.

Comment: Do not post duplicate answers. If you find that two different questions require the same answer, then likely one of them is a dupe. In such a case, please flag appropriately.