# A fresh install boots to the grub command prompt

Tags: grub

I've a problem when I'm installing elementary OS Freya on a Sony VAIO 13".

First of all I read all the posts on the forum which treat that subject

My problem is when I install elementary OS, after installing it rebooted automatically and at the boot I've got a GRUB Screen : "Grub > ..."

I don't know how to fix it. I've change some configuration in my BIOS (disabled UEFI and Secure Boot) but nothing has changed. I've tried to fix the problem by [following these steps](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1), but it didn't help.

But, when I boot on my USB drive and if I choose "Try elementary" instead of "Install" it works, and runs fine.

Comment: Hey Matt, it depends on whether you want EFI turned on or not. Try taking a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair and let me know what you get.

Answer (score 2):

Boot using your live CD. Then you need to run these commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Boot repair will now open. Click on "advanced options" and search for the option that mentions "purge grub". Than click "recommended repair" and follow the on screen messages. When that's done you can reboot and if everything went right it will work now.

Comment: Do not post duplicate answers. If you find that two different questions require the same answer, then likely one of them is a dupe. In such a case, please flag appropriately.

Comment: @RolandiXor what if they aren't duplicates? Just personalise the answer?