# Install elementary OS alongside Windows - Got problems

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I installed elementary OS Freya alongside Windows on an Asus Laptop. Installation goes well, but when I reboot to finally use elementary OS, I get only a black screen, `grub>` console.

Previously I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (alongside Windows) and everything was fine.

The only mod I did when I was running Ubuntu, was hide the grub menu to run Ubuntu by default without ask, but keeping Windows on disk.

Any help will be apreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem after installation of Elementary OS Freya](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2480/problem-after-installation-of-elementary-os-freya)

Comment: @Jeroen That's solution does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many solutions for this on the web, I used another one not listed here, that's why my answer. This is the workaroud I used:

- Install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
- Go to Advanced options
- Look for 'purge grub' option
- Follow the steps

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the problem of Freya booting straight to the Grub console after installation. However, I did not have dual boot.

I managed to fix the issue by following the steps laid out by Rob Hartley in the following link:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801

Maybe it helps you, too! Good luck with it. After that initial hick up and some configuration I am starting to really like my laptop with elementary OS on it and I hope you have a similarly good experience!

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same problem since 2 weeks and I managed to recover just yesterday.

I also have an asus vivobook and I was also stuck at grub (you can even go further and boot to a busybox/initramfs prompt but it's not helping).

You have to install elementary 0.3 released on 2015-04-11. I think it handles in a much better way the boot than the 0.3.1 version.
So just do a live usb of 0.3 and install it to replace 0.3.1

Once 0.3 is installed, the update manager will install all the updates from 0.3.1 :)

cheers