# After repair grub error to boot SO

Tags: grub

Good day,  I tried to boot the elementary OS after repair grub ([How can I fix a secure boot failing to grub when I installed 0.3.1?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)), but he has returned me the error attached in the picture and I can no longer access the OS.. also i can´t reach Elementary OS booting from USB pen drive (stuck on black screen)

I´m on a Lenovo z40-70 and win8.1

[image: error: verification failed]

Thanks to response from @Ravan.

Comment: try this:  disable secure boot in the bios security tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar problem.The solution is

```
disable secure boot in the bios security tab
```