# Grub command line after installing 0.3.1 Freya

Tags: grub

I know this has been answered before since I've spent the last few hours attempting to get it to work: [How can I fix a secure boot failing to grub when I installed 0.3.1?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)

However, after trying this method with all the options available from ls I still can't get Elementary OS to load. There is no automatic boot or anything.

No idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using the above link and re-creating the freya USB stick using unetboot instead of rufus.