# Booting into GRUB after installing on top of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub, ubuntu

Installed over Ubuntu 14.04 which was installed over OS X on an old MacBook Pro. Greeted with the GRUB bootloader. I have seen [this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1) but I have an extra issue that prevents me from using the workaround: when I do an ls, I am shown:

```
(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (cd0) error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd0'.
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'cd0'.
```

Looking at (hd1,1) I found the folder:

```
(hd1,1)/efi/grub/grub.cfg
```

Which, when I run the command

```
configfile (hd1,1)/efi/grub/grub.cfg
```

Gives me the option to boot into GNU/Linux. Then the screen just goes black.

I can't seem to get to the point where I can do the workaround suggested in the first thread linked here.

I ran boot-repair and [here is the log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13242621/)

Comment: I forgot to say: I do SELECT the option to boot into GNU/Linux. At that point, the screen goes black.

Comment: I plugged the disk into my Windows PC and used the diskpart command line application to clean the disk, then tried reinstalling. I am greeted with the same GRUB prompt with the same ls output. I believe that Elementary OS is on hd0, but I cannot access it because of the "failure reading sector" error. I have learned that setting (hd1,1)/efi/grub/grub.cfg as my boot script tries to boot me into an Ubuntu Linux that is not there