# Error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd0'

Tags: system-installation, grub

On installing Elementary OS I am greeted with GRUB when I restart, however, the [workaround for this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1) does not work because I cannot access the drive with Elementary on it. When I do an ls, I am greeted with:

```
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd0'.
```

I am using a blank SSD cleaned with diskpart using Windows.

Please help!

Comment: You need to provide more information, like dual boot? UEFI or BIOS? from linked post, it seems UEFI, correct?

Comment: [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219563/cant-even-try-ubuntu-due-to-error-failure-reading-sector-0x5b500-from-hd1) if useful =)

Comment: I am doing a fresh install on an SSD that had Ubuntu Linux 14.04 on it first. The machine was running OS X before, using a separate HDD. Ideally the only operating system on there will be Elementary OS. How do I tell if I am using UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Ravan. You are a true Internet friend. I have solved the problem by installing OS X