# How do I boot elementary OS 0.3.2 after initial install?

Tags: system-installation, grub, usb-drive

Using 0.3.2, acpi=off, and nomodeset flags I was able to single boot elementary OS from USB and successfully install. I haven't been able to successfully restart.

When restarting I'm dropped into grub. I've attempted the fix found in another [popular thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1) of entering `configfile (hd0,gpt2)/grub/grub.cfg` and then loading elementary OS. I've tried loading elementary OS with and without acpi=off and nomodeset flags after the `splash` flag.

How can I reboot elementary OS in this situation?

Referenced Question: [How can I fix a secure boot failing to grub when I installed 0.3.1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)?

Edit: I noticed that in the thread the fix is under the /boot namespace. Could it be an issue that I don't have /boot in grub?

Edit: It may be relevant that I chose to encrypt my installation disk and opted for LVM - logical volume management.

Answer (score -1):

you probably want to try

configfile (hd0,gpt2)/efi/grub/grub.cfg instead

have a good one... i still havent found a permanent fix :*(

Answer (score -1):

1. configfile (hd0,gpt2)/efi/grub/grub.cfg
2. boot in recovery mode under advanced settings in GRUB
3. install nvidia graphic card drivers

Now when I restart or power on it boots cleanly through to elementary OS. Thanks for your help cedric!